Script doesnt recognize bars / length right for cutting audio , ffmpeg terminal
This terminal script doesn't recognize bars / length right for cutting audio, maybe somebody knows what's wrong with the calculation ...
Would be happy about any help the cutting already works!
#!/bin/bash

# Function to extract BPM from filename

get_bpm() {
    local filename="$1"
    local bpm=$(echo "$filename" | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}' | head -n1)
    echo "$bpm"
}

# Function to cut audio based on BPM
cut_audio() {
    local input_file="$1"
    local bpm="$2"
    local output_file="${input_file%.*}_cut.${input_file##*.}" # Appends "_cut" to original filename

    # Define the number of beats per bar (assuming 4 beats per bar)
    beats_per_bar=4

    # Calculate the duration of each bar in seconds
    bar_duration=$((60 * beats_per_bar / bpm))

    # Define start and end times for each bar range
    start_times=(0 21 33 45 57 69 81 93 105 117 129 141)
    end_times=(20 29 41 53 65 77 89 101 113 125 137 149)

    # Iterate through each bar range
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#start_times[@]}; i++)); do
        start_time=${start_times[$i]}
        end_time=${end_times[$i]}
        echo "Cutting audio file $input_file at $bpm BPM for bar $((i + 1)) ($start_time-$end_time) for $bar_duration seconds..."

        # Cut audio for current bar range using ffmpeg
        ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -ss "$start_time" -to "$end_time" -c copy "$output_file"_"$((i + 1)).${input_file##*.}" -y
    done

    # Check if the output files are empty and delete them if so
    for output_file in "${output_file}"_*; do
        if [ ! -s "$output_file" ]; then
            echo "Output file $output_file is empty. Deleting..."
            rm "$output_file"
        fi
    done

    echo "Audio cut and saved as $output_file"
}


# Main script
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [audio_file1] [audio_file2] ..."
    exit 1
fi

for file in "$@"; do
    bpm=$(get_bpm "$file")
    if [ -z "$bpm" ]; then
        echo "Error: No BPM found in filename $file"
    else
        cut_audio "$file" "$bpm"
    fi
done

Maybe its only the math calc in the beginning but idk :)
If you need more details just lmk

"Maybe its only the math calc". Seems very likely. As is, this is way to much to ask readers to plow thru to help debug. Please read about [mcve] AND, more specifically to your problem, read the section How to turn a bad script into a good question If you follow this advice, you are likely to solve the problem yourself. Good luck.
